# Android Box API unable to function after initial OAuth

Tags: android, oauth, box-api, boxapiv2

I'm working with the Box API with Android. I'm using Android Studio and testing on the simulator.

I have a button that I'm using to initiate the OAuth request, after authenticating, I return to my app and a different button should show up to perform other tasks (I plan on adding get free/used/total space).

I'm using the following code, but once I return to my app, the other button doesn't show up and if I click my initial button, nothing happens.

Can anybody point me into the right direction please?

Thanks.

```
private void getUserIdUsingBox() {
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_ID = BoxController.BOX_CLIENT_ID;
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_SECRET = BoxController.BOX_SECRET;
    BoxSession session = new BoxSession(this);
    session.authenticate();

} //getUserIdsUsingBox

public void onLinkBox(View view) { getUserIdUsingBox(); }

private void invalidate() {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("List of available controllers: ");
    for (Controller controller : mManager.getAvailableControllers()) {
        msg.append("\n" + controller.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    mText.setText(msg);

    List<LinkedAccount> linkedAccounts = mManager.getAvailableAccounts();
    for (LinkedAccount acct : linkedAccounts) {
        if (acct.getServiceName().equals(GoogleDriveController.NAME)) {
            mLinkGoogleDriveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTestGoogleDriveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (acct.getServiceName().equals(DropboxController.NAME)) {
            mLinkDropboxButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTestDropboxButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (acct.getServiceName().equals(BoxController.NAME))
        {
            mLinkBoxButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTestBoxButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more of your code? It's not clear how your UI logic and onClick callbacks are wired up.

Comment: I've now included some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As greg mentioned -- it would be helpful to see your UI logic. But something like this should work:

```
    final Button btnToAuthenticate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auth_box_btn);
    final Button btnAfterAuthenticate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box_action_btn);
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_ID = BoxController.BOX_CLIENT_ID;
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_SECRET = BoxController.BOX_SECRET;
    BoxSession session = new BoxSession(this);

    btnToAuthenticate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mSession.authenticate();
        }
    });
    mSession.setSessionAuthListener(new BoxAuthentication.AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefreshed(BoxAuthentication.BoxAuthenticationInfo boxAuthenticationInfo) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthCreated(BoxAuthentication.BoxAuthenticationInfo boxAuthenticationInfo) {
            btnAfterAuthenticate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthFailure(BoxAuthentication.BoxAuthenticationInfo boxAuthenticationInfo, Exception e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggedOut(BoxAuthentication.BoxAuthenticationInfo boxAuthenticationInfo, Exception e) {

        }
    });
```